# primefaces component id not found in update

Tags: jsf, primefaces

this is my form

```
<form id=frmCalculation>
<p:messages id="msgs" showDetail="true" showSummary="false" redisplay="false" closable="true" escape="false" />
<panel>
<panelgrid id=statpanel>
</panelgrid>
<datatable id=dtEnrich>
<p:ajax event="filter" listener="#{enrichmentView.doFilter}" update="@this " />
<p:column filterby... filterMatchMode...>
...
</datatable>
</panel>
</form>
```

In statpanel there are several outputText controls, which i want to update every time, when something is filtered in the datagrid.
In enrichmentview.doFilter I setup the new values for those fields, which are bound to the outputText controls.

But in ajax tag, I cannot figure out what should be the component id to put in order to update the outputText controls, and of course the datatable to update it due to the filters.

I tried with "statpanel", ":statpanel", ":frmCalculation:statpanel". every time i have an error that statpanel control is not found.
Or it is also possible that I want to display a message in msgs, but it also doesn't work.

when I put @form or "frmCalculation", the outputTexts are updated, but then the datatable rows/columns are collapsed (i can only see the cell values in one long string)

Comment: @JasperdeVries Well, it helps. I understand that panelGrid is not a NamingContainer. However unfortunately my form is more complicated, because the form tag is defined in different xhtml, and the panelgrid, datatable is defined in a composite view. so, I cannot create another form to include the panelGrid.
in generated html the real id is frmCalculation:j_idt53:statpanel. and putting this to update, it works. but i believe that j_idtxx is a generated identifier, i shouldn't be use.
Still don't know what should be the solution

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the solution was to add widgetVar to the panel tag (parent of panelGrid).

```
<p:panel widgetVar="widget_pnl">
  <p:panelGrid id="statpanel" columns="3" layout="grid">
```

Then in update I could use

```
<p:ajax event="filter" listener="#{enrichmentView.doFilter}" update="@this @widgetVar(widget_pnl):statpanel " />
```

Comment: This is just a workaround.

Comment: This that I am doing is to go to the browser and find the id from the inspect element